# How can you add a rule mark that interactively displays the average on the linked chart in a brushing and linking interaction?

Tags: altair

I have been working through the Altair visualization curriculum [Interaction Colab notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/github/uwdata/visualization-curriculum/blob/master/altair_interaction.ipynb).

I am trying to do the following exercise from the end of the notebook:

*Putting into action what we've learned so far: can you modify the movie scatter plot above (the one with the dynamic query over years) to include a rule mark that shows the average IMDB (or Rotten Tomatoes) rating for the data contained within the year interval selection?*

I have tried this from many angles, but am unable to figure out the solution. This is my current code, which causes a specification error:

```
brush = alt.selection_interval(
    encodings=['x'] # limit selection to x-axis (year) values
)

label = alt.selection_single(
    encodings=['x'], # limit selection to x-axis value
    on='mouseover',  # select on mouseover events
    nearest=True,    # select data point nearest the cursor
    empty='none'     # empty selection includes no data points
)

# dynamic query histogram
years = alt.Chart(movies).mark_bar().add_selection(
    brush
).encode(
    alt.X('year(Release_Date):T', title='Films by Release Year'),
    alt.Y('count():Q', title=None)
).properties(
    width=650,
    height=50
)

# scatter plot, modify opacity based on selection
ratings = alt.Chart(movies).mark_circle().encode(
    x='Rotten_Tomatoes_Rating:Q',
    y='IMDB_Rating:Q',
    tooltip='Title:N',
    opacity=alt.condition(brush, alt.value(0.75), alt.value(0.05))
).properties(
    width=650,
    height=400
).add_selection(label)

line = alt.Chart(movies).mark_rule(color='firebrick').encode(
    x='Rotten_Tomatoes_Rating:Q',
    size=alt.SizeValue(1)
).transform_filter(
    label
)

text = ratings.mark_text(align='left', dx=5, dy=-5).encode(
    text='mean(Rotten_Tomatoes_Rating):Q'
).transform_filter(label)

alt.vconcat(years, ratings + line + text).properties(spacing=5)
```

How might I go about solving this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same strategy as [in this example in the docs](https://altair-viz.github.io/gallery/selection_layer_bar_month.html):

```py
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data

source = data.seattle_weather()
brush = alt.selection_interval(encodings=['x'])

bars = alt.Chart().mark_bar().encode(
    x='month(date):O',
    y='mean(precipitation):Q',
    opacity=alt.condition(brush, alt.OpacityValue(1), alt.OpacityValue(0.7)),
).add_params(
    brush
)

line = alt.Chart().mark_rule(color='firebrick').encode(
    y='mean(precipitation):Q',
    size=alt.SizeValue(3)
).transform_filter(
    brush
)

alt.layer(bars, line, data=source)
```